# ngrx - map does not exists on {}

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observablecollection

Sharing what I found. 
I was able to get past the issue by using the spread and then recreate the array of object returned by the firestore observable. Solution: replace .pipe(map((docArray) => by .pipe(map(([...docArray]) =>

```
this.dbisFirestore.db
            .collection('main01featureDB')
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(map((docArray) => {     
            return docArray.map(doc => {    // Issue - map does not exists on {}  
            transformed_doc = ...
            return transformed_doc
                     });
              }))
              .subscribe(...
```

As below - works

```
    this.dbisFirestore.db
            .collection('main01featureDB')
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(map(([...docArray]) => {  // Resolution
            return docArray.map(doc => {    
            transformed_doc = ...
            return transformed_doc
                     });
              }))
              .subscribe(...);
```

May be someone will find it helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It's seems that the problem is that ts doesn't reconize that the result is an arrray, maybe try to convert it to an array for example use:
return (docArray as any[]).map(doc => { ....})

Comment: Thanks that works too.